# Dynamically added item to ng-repeat hold duplicate model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I 'm creating a web page where I 'm providing option to the user to dynamically add line items. I have used angularjs framework (v 1.4.7). I was able to achieve the effect of dynamically adding item to the ng-repeat but the modal seems to be not unique amongst the dynamically added items.

Here is demo code showing the problem:

```
<div>
<form novalidate class="form-vertical" ng-show="!loading" name="detailsForm" ng-controller="DetailsCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="social in socials track by $index">
      <ng-form name="urlForm">
            <input type="email" name="socialUrl" ng-model="social.email">
            <span class="alert error" ng-show="urlForm.socialUrl.$error.email">Email error</span>
      </ng-form>
  </div>  
  <a title="Add" class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:void(null)" ng-click="addSocial()"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i> Add</a>
</form>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('DetailsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    var social = {"email":""};

    $scope.socials = [
            { email: 'test@test.com'},
        { email: 'invalid email'}];


  $scope.addSocial = function(){
    $scope.socials.push(social);
  };

    }]
    );
```

I have created the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9vr7ohn/6/) showing the problem. In the fiddle, please add a new item "12345@email.com". Add another item "54321@email.com". You will notice that the item added at first is also changed when typing in the second one.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9vr7ohn/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're adding the same object to the array and then you don't assign your social to a new object. This way angular keeps it's bindings.

[Here's your fix](http://jsfiddle.net/Voreny/c9vr7ohn/7/):

```
$scope.addSocial = function(){
    $scope.socials.push(social);
    social = {"email": ""};
  };
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Voreny. You made my day :)